# CompoundPropertyModel - converting a boolean value before rendering

Tags: java, wicket

I'm using a CompoundPropertyModel (via PropertyListView) to print properties of an object (User).

One of the properties of the User object is a boolean. I would like the boolean to be rendered using a custom conversion (false -> "disabled", true -> "enabled").

How can I achieve this without adding new method to the User object?

```java
add(new PropertyListView<User>("users", new LoadableUsersModel()) {
    @Override
    protected void populateItem(ListItem<User> item) {
        item.add(new Label("firstname"));
        item.add(new Label("surname"));
        item.add(new Label("username"));
        item.add(new Label("email"));
        item.add(new Label("active"));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this:

- Get your Model Object from `item`, and use an `if-else`.

  ```
  User user = item.getModelObject();
  item.add(new Label("active", user.isActive() ? "enabled" : "disabled"));
  ```
- Implement an `IConverter` and return the desired value in its `convertToString()` method. Return an instance of the converter in an override of the `getConverter()` method of the `Label`. In this example it's all anonymous classes, it'd be better to define them as independent classes, at least the converter, and have a static method to use just a single instance.

  ```
  item.add(new Label("active"){
      public IConverter getConverter(Class type){
          return new IConverter(){
              public String convertToString(Object value, Locale locale){
                  if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(value) { return "enabled"; }
                  else if (Boolean.FALSE.equals(value) { return "disabled"; }
                  else { return null; }
              }
              public Object convertToObject(String value, Locale locale){
                  // Not needed, only used by FormComponents
                  return null;
              }
           }
      }
  };
  ```
- Use an `AbstractReadOnlyModel` to return the desired value, feeding it with the `active` property, or a Model with it:

  ```
  PropertyModel pm = new PropertyModel(item.getModel(), "active");
  item.add(new Label("active", new AbstractReadOnlyModel(){
      public Object getObject() { 
          if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(pm.getObject()) { return "enabled"; }
          else if (Boolean.FALSE.equals(pm.getObject()) { return "disabled"; }
          else { return null; }
      }
  }));
  ```

As a side note, if `enabled` and `disabled` are literals that are to be shown in the page, you might be interested in localizing them in a xml resource file, and use `getString()` instead.

Comment: Very comprehensive answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the methods mentioned by Xavi López there is another one, maybe preferable when you plan to localize your application. You could use a [StringresourceModel](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/model/StringResourceModel.html) like

```
add(new Label("active", 
        new StringResourceModel("active.${active}", 
        new Model<String> item.getModel().getActive().toString())));
```

and define an resource.file (I'd prefer XML), defining active.true=enabled and active.falsee=disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [custom converter](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/using-custom-converters.html). (See [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/working-with-wicket-models.html#WorkingwithWicketmodels-WrappedObjectModels) for another example (somewhere in the middle)).
But it seems that in just this case you would have less work with a simple if/else construct.